# How to Compile SASS in a Wordpress Child Theme?

Tags: wordpress, sass

I am trying to figure out how to compile SASS in a child theme and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

I built a parent theme based on jointsWP. Here is the file structure for the library of the parent theme:

[image]

Then I built a child theme. Here's the file structure for the library of the child theme:

[image]

In the root of my child theme, I have a style.css with the necessary child theme comments:

```
/*
 Theme Name:   UIC
 Theme URI:    http://slamagency.com
 Description:  Child theme of the SLAM! theme for UIC.
 Author:       Megan Carroll
 Template:     slam-theme_v1
 Version:      1.0.0
 Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
*/
/* =Theme customization starts here
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

@import url("../slam-theme_v1/css/style.css")
```

Then in Library > SCSS > style.scss, I have the following code:

```
@import "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,700italic,400,300,700";

//
// IMPORTING STYLES
//

// Load SLAM! Theme parent SCSS.
@import url("../slam-theme_v1/scss/style.scss");

// import mixins
@import "mixins";

// import foundation overrides
@import "settings";

// import child colors
@import "colors";
```

**EDIT**: To clarify, when I add something in style.scss, it does compile to style.css. But if I make any changes to _settings.scss, nothing happens. I'm using Foundation, so I'd like to be able to edit the Foundation variables in _settings.scss. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT 2**: Here is the code that is in my config file for my child theme:

```
# 1. Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"

# 2. probably don't need to touch these
css_dir = "../css"
sass_dir = "./"
images_dir = "../images"
javascripts_dir = "../js"
environment = :development
relative_assets = true


# 3. You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden via the command line):
output_style = :expanded

# 4. When you are ready to launch your WP theme comment out (3) and uncomment the line below
# output_style = :compressed

# To disable debugging comments that display the original location of your selectors. Uncomment:
# line_comments = false

# don't touch this
preferred_syntax = :scss
```

**EDIT 3**: Requested enqueue code from parent theme:

```
// loading modernizr and jquery, and reply script
if (!function_exists('slam_scripts_and_styles')) { 
function slam_scripts_and_styles() {
  global $wp_styles; // call global $wp_styles variable to add conditional wrapper around ie stylesheet the WordPress way
  if (!is_admin()) {
    $theme_version = wp_get_theme()->Version;

    // removes WP version of jQuery
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');

    // loads jQuery 2.1.0
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bower_components/foundation/js/vendor/jquery.js', array(), '2.1.0', false );

    // modernizr (without media query polyfill)
    wp_enqueue_script( 'modernizr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bower_components/foundation/js/vendor/modernizr.js', array(), '2.5.3', false );

    // adding Foundation scripts file in the footer
    wp_enqueue_script( 'foundation-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), $theme_version, true );

/*
    // register main stylesheet
    wp_enqueue_style( 'slam-stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/css/style.css', array(), $theme_version, 'all' );
*/

    // register foundation icons
    wp_enqueue_style( 'foundation-icons', get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/css/icons/foundation-icons.css', array(), $theme_version, 'all' );

    // comment reply script for threaded comments
    if ( is_singular() AND comments_open() AND (get_option('thread_comments') == 1)) {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }

    //adding scripts file in the footer
    wp_enqueue_script( 'slam-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/js/scripts.js', array( 'jquery' ), $theme_version, true );

    /*
    I recommend using a plugin to call jQuery
    using the google cdn. That way it stays cached
    and your site will load faster.
    */
    wp_enqueue_script( 'slam-js' );

  }
}
}
```

Earlier in the parent functions there is this:

```
// enqueue base scripts and styles
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'slam_scripts_and_styles', 999);
```

Comment: We need to know how you're triggering compilation of SASS.  Are you running 'sass --watch', 'compass watch', using grunt, or using something like JetBrains' File Watchers (PyCharm/PHPStorm/RubyMine/etc), or some other method?  Each of those methods will have a way that you specify what files to watch for changes.  Please post the configuration for that method.  So for compass for example, that would be your config.rb file.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I wrote that in there but I guess I didn't. I use the [Scout app](http://mhs.github.io/scout-app/) to compile.

Comment: Ok so with scout, it would have setup the config.rb file for you (so you don't have to worry about it).  but still, would you mind posting it?

Comment: @manishie See above for the config code.

Comment: I should mention that when I write a new style in _settings.scss, it does show up in style.css. But when I try to change any of the existing variables, nothing happens in style.css. I'm guessing it's because I'm not loading the Foundation styles from the parent theme correctly, so when I change a variable and recompile, the theme doesn't see anywhere to put the new variable. But I can't figure out how to load the Foundation styles from the parent theme...

Comment: what do you mean change the existing variables?  in which file are those variables located?

Comment: I'm turning this into an answer.  See below in a few...

Comment: Actually try this first and if it works I'll turn it into an anser and summarize.  From the child theme style.css, comment out the import line.  I think what's happening is that you're importing the parent styles, and also trying to compile you're own styles again in the child theme.

Comment: If I remove the import line, the site stays the same. I think the problem is that Wordpress is loading my child styles before my parent styles. I have tried to dequeue the parent styles, but it isn't working... If I comment out the wp_enqueue_styles line in the parent theme, the child styles show up. But I don't want to do that, because then the parent theme is useless.

Comment: Why would that make the parent theme useless?  You should just copy the entire sass folder to your own child theme, use wp_dequeue_style to get rid of the parent style, and do all of your sass work in the child theme.

Comment: Well, if I edit the parent theme and comment out the function that calls the stylesheet, doesn't that make the parent theme pointless? If it's never queuing the styles? I tried wp_dequeue_style and it doesn't work.

Comment: the parent theme has a lot besides the stylesheets.  it's got all of the php code, which you're still using.  please show me the code you used to dequeue the style

Comment: <?php

//Remove Parent Styles
function remove_parent_styles() {

 wp_dequeue_style( 'slam-stylesheet' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_parent_styles', 25);

?>

Comment: are you sure that 'slam-stylesheet' is the same handle being used in the parent theme?  and fyi, this new function should go in your new functions.php in the child theme.  you should never be editing anything in the parent theme directly.

Comment: Yes that is the correct handle, and yes I put it in my functions.php in my child theme.

Comment: can you update the question with the code used to enqueue the style in the parent (including the add_action and the full function call).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61379/discussion-between-mcography-and-manishie).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize our findings from our comments & chat:

- Copy the entire sass directory into the child theme.  Then when you edit a variable, everything gets recompiled.
- In the child theme, don't import the styles from the parent theme since we're now recompiling in the child theme.
- Since in this case there was an enqueue statement in the parent theme loading the style, we need to dequeue that style in the child theme.  And you need to set the priority of the hook so that your dequeue gets called AFTER the enqueue (which had a priority of 999).

The code:

```
function uic_styles() { 
  wp_dequeue_style( 'slam-stylesheet' ); 
  wp_enqueue_style( 'slam-stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/css/style.css' ); 
  wp_enqueue_style( 'uic-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/css/style.css' ); 
} 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'uic_styles', 1000 );
```

Comment: Did you mean Copy the entire sass directory into the **Child** theme

Answer (score 2):

The SCSS file in my parent theme

'theme-name/assets/scss/style.scss'

```
@import "base/fonts";
@import "variables/all";
@import "underscores/style";
@import "wordpress-overrides";
@import "inc/init";
```

The SCSS file in my child theme

'theme-name-child/assets/scss/style.scss'

```
/*
Theme Name:   Theme Name Child
Theme URI:    
Description:  Theme Name Child Theme
Author:       Theme Name, Co.
Author URI:   
Template:     ow
Version:      1.0.0
License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Tags:         responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
Text Domain:  my-name-theme-child
*/


/* My Name Parent Theme Styles */
/* --------------------------- */
@import "../../../theme-name/assets/scss/style";



/* My Name Child Theme Styles */
/* -------------------------- */

/* Base */
@import "base/fonts";
@import "variables/all";
@import "base/mixins";
@import "base/base";

/* Templates */
@import "templates/template-menu";

/* Inc */
@import "inc/init";
```

**I compile** 'theme-name-child/assets/scss/style.scss' **into** 'theme-name-child/style.css'