# How to run sass in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, sass

I have theme and I add sass and gulp in my theme. here are the list of file I have.
[image]

I would like to ask How can I run sass in my theme? I try to google it, but no right explanation how they did it. I found this also [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25796987/how-to-compile-sass-in-a-wordpress-child-theme), but no clear explanation. Please help me. I want to learn more about sass. If you have tutorial. please give me link.
sorry i didn't mention the OS I used. I used windows.

Comment: You have to compile sass locally. As I can see you are using windows. There are a lot of tutorials how to use sass with compass for windows.

Comment: I use git bash to do this. I thought it the same in laravel. but laravel has already app.scss installed. I will try to search the compass. thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `assets` folder. All source files including `.scss` files must be there. Then add gulp task to compile scss. It will take files from `assets` folder and put them to `dest` folder (`dest` folder is for compiled resources). Then add link to compiled `.css` file from `dest` to wp header.

[Tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-gulp-for-wordpress-automation--cms-23081).

Comment: thanks for this. I got it now. It's a long study. hehehe. save my day

Answer (score 1):

Please follow steps mentioned [here](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-use-sass-with-wordpress-a-step-by-step-guide)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: hi. thanks for this, but very hard in windows. I think this is easy if I used ubunto.

Answer (score 0):

Also, look at setting up a child theme, then you can keep all your code isolated.